# Need Help recovering my EFI partition

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Last week I formatted my PC to install Kubuntu 20.10 on my new NVMe disk (I also formatted my EFI partition). Before that, I had Ubuntu 20.10 installed on my other SSD drive. The problem is that after the Kubuntu installation, I can no longer boot into Ubuntu anymore. Kubuntu (on the NVMe drive) boots as expected, however Ubuntu (on the other disk) does not boot, although it is listed by Grub when I turn on the PC.

Here is the summarized output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048    999423    997376   487M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 999424 976771071 975771648 465,3G Linux filesystem

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 1172260863 1172258816   559G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1172260864 1875384319  703123456 335,3G 83 Linux
```

So in short, `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is where the EFI partition is located. I already mounted it and it has two folders: EFI/BOOT and EFI/ubuntu (I guess this is actually used by Kubuntu).

The partition `/dev/nvme0n1p2` is where Kubuntu is installed (all is fine here). The partition `/dev/sdb1` is where Ubuntu 20.10 is installed and the partition `/dev/sdb2` is used to store backups.

From what I read in other questions posted by users, when I formatted the EFI partition, I lost the information needed to boot Ubuntu 20.10 again. However, I do not know how to fix this issue. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Is 20.10 installed in UEFI boot mode. If both installs are UEFI, the `sudo update-grub` should add any other UEFI installs to your grub menu. Typically you only have one Ubuntu entry in UEFI and then grub offers to boot all other Linux installs.

Comment: I've already done that. I ran `sudo update-grub` with all partitions mounted. It identifies both operating systems, they appear in grub when I turn on my PC, but when I select Ubuntu 20.10 on /dev/sdb1, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you select recovery mode and then what happens?

Comment: I chose the recovery mode and nothing happened. All I got was a black screen and Ctrl Alt Del did nor work to restart the PC.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Is other install using LVM or other configuration? And then does a boot stanza in its grub load other .mod files like insmod lvm?

Comment: Hil @oldfred, sorry for taking so long. It's my first time handling boot issues. Here's the link to the boot-info report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xmGD7bvkrS/

Comment: Do not know why you are showing so many entries in grub and so many kernels. You normally only get one entry for each install plus recovery and it normally keeps only two kernels. You also show two installs on sdb. And you show bad fstab entries, which may be why they do not boot. Try mounting each install in sdb and comment out the ESP - efi system partition entry. It looks like you deleted the original ESP. Also sdb is MBR partitioned which will work with Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but Windows requires & UEFI wants gpt partitioned drives. If you elect to reinstall, I would also convert drive.

Comment: On sdb1 I have the Ubuntu installation I want to boot again. On sdb2 I have some remnants of old distro-hopping installations (the latest was Kubuntu 20.10 to test it before finally installing it on my NVMe drive). I do not have Windows on my machine. Do you think running the Auto Fix on Boot-repair is recommended in my case?

Comment: Only run an advanced fix if using Boot-Repair with multiple drives & multiple installs. In advanced mode you choose a drive and choose a location to install grub. If UEFI and you have an ESP on second drive, you then can also install grub to second drive where Ubiquity installer only lets you install to first drive. I prefer to have each drive bootable, but since usually using live installer to fix things, not required. Another advantage of ESP on sdb, is just as a backup of ESP on sda. I typically have ESP on every drive & use 30GB for / for test installs.

Comment: I am out of lucky here. I ran Boot-Repair with automatic settings on my PC and nothing was fixed. I still can't boot my sdb1 partition with Ubuntu 20.10. At least my Kubuntu installation is still booting fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose install in sdb1 and install its grub to sdb drive. That should not change boot of Kubuntu in sda. Then in BIOS choose to boot sdb?